# How can I open a specific dataset (band) from a multi dataset MODIS image using Rasterio? Rasterio IndexError: band index out of range

Tags: python, rasterio

How can I open a specific dataset from a multi dataset MODIS image using Rasterio?

I have posted some sample data on GitHub: https://github.com/SteveObert/rasterIO_question/tree/master/data

If I open a MODIS HDF file with only one band the code below works the way I want it to:

```
import rasterio

rasterfileMulti = 'MOD10A1_multiband_HEGOUT.hdf'
rasterfileSingle = 'MOD10A1_singleband_HEGOUT.hdf'
shapeFile = 'SFP_drainage.shp'


# Read an HDF into an array

dataset = rasterio.open('rasterfileSingle')
band1 = dataset.read(1)
print(band1)
```

The output:

```
array([[ 53,  53, 250, ..., 255, 255, 255],
   [ 56,  56,  56, ..., 255, 255, 255],
   [ 56,  56,  49, ..., 255, 255, 255],
   ...,
   [ 78,  78,  78, ...,  53,  50,  50],
   [ 72,  78,  78, ...,  57,  57,  57],
   [ 72,  72,  72, ...,  61,  61,  61]], dtype=uint8)
```

However, If I try to open a MODIS HDF file with multiple data sets I get the error "Rasterio IndexError: band index out of range" as below.

```
rasterfileMulti = MOD10A1_multiband_HEGOUT.hdf

dataset2 = rasterio.open('rasterfileMulti')
band1 = dataset.read(1)
print(band1)
```

The error from the code above looks like this:

```
/Users/steve/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rasterio/__init__.py:193: UserWarning: Dataset has no geotransform set.  Default transform will be applied (Affine.identity())
s.start()
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-9-584312f89d76>", line 3, in <module>
band1 = dataset.read(1)

File "rasterio/_io.pyx", line 720, in rasterio._io.RasterReader.read

IndexError: band index out of range
```

Ultimately, I want to clip the raster to a shapefile. The code below works the way I want as long as the Modis image only has one band, 'NDSI_Snow_Cover' in this case.

```
import fiona
import rasterio
rasterfileSingle = MOD10A1_singleband_HEGOUT.hdf
shapeFile = SFP_drainage.shp

with fiona.open(shapeFile, 'r') as shapefile:
    features = [feature['geometry'] for feature in shapefile]


with rasterio.open(rasterfileMulti) as src:
    out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, features,
                                                        crop=True)
    out_meta = src.meta.copy()


out_meta.update({'driver': 'GTiff',
                 'height': out_image.shape[1],
                 'width': out_image.shape[2],
                 'transform': out_transform})
with      rasterio.open('/Users/steve/Documents/classes/Geos_505/project_Payette/working/data_files/test_clip_out.tif', 'w', **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(out_image)
```

Comment: You are reading from dataset instead of dataset2 on your multi band example.

Comment: I've tried it with both datasets (and several others as well). It seems like rasterio is complaining about the colons.

Comment: Try with open('subdataset'). Yesterday I edited my answer and removed the single quotes.

Comment: Adding the outer single quotes works: rasterio.open('HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD10A1_multiband_HEGOUT.hdf":MOD_Grid_Snow_500m_16:NDSI_Snow_Cover')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we need to know the name of the subdataset. gdalinfo gives the following 7 subdatasets:

```
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD10A1_multiband_HEGOUT.hdf":MOD_Grid_Snow_500m_16:NDSI_Snow_Cover
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[350x831] NDSI_Snow_Cover MOD_Grid_Snow_500m_16 (8-bit unsigned integer)           
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD10A1_multiband_HEGOUT.hdf":MOD_Grid_Snow_500m_16:NDSI_Snow_Cover_Basic_QA
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=[350x831] NDSI_Snow_Cover_Basic_QA MOD_Grid_Snow_500m_16 (8-bit unsigned integer)
  SUBDATASET_3_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD10A1_multiband_HEGOUT.hdf":MOD_Grid_Snow_500m_16:NDSI_Snow_Cover_Algorithm_Flags_QA
  SUBDATASET_3_DESC=[350x831] NDSI_Snow_Cover_Algorithm_Flags_QA MOD_Grid_Snow_500m_16 (8-bit unsigned integer)
  SUBDATASET_4_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD10A1_multiband_HEGOUT.hdf":MOD_Grid_Snow_500m_16:NDSI
  SUBDATASET_4_DESC=[350x831] NDSI MOD_Grid_Snow_500m_16 (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_5_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD10A1_multiband_HEGOUT.hdf":MOD_Grid_Snow_500m_16:Snow_Albedo_Daily_Tile
  SUBDATASET_5_DESC=[350x831] Snow_Albedo_Daily_Tile MOD_Grid_Snow_500m_16 (8-bit unsigned integer)
  SUBDATASET_6_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD10A1_multiband_HEGOUT.hdf":MOD_Grid_Snow_500m_16:orbit_pnt
  SUBDATASET_6_DESC=[350x831] orbit_pnt MOD_Grid_Snow_500m_16 (8-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_7_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD10A1_multiband_HEGOUT.hdf":MOD_Grid_Snow_500m_16:granule_pnt
  SUBDATASET_7_DESC=[350x831] granule_pnt MOD_Grid_Snow_500m_16 (8-bit unsigned integer)
```

Now, you can open any subdaset passing GDAL fully-qualified name of the subdataset as argument. For example:

```
rasterio.open('HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD10A1_multiband_HEGOUT.hdf":MOD_Grid_Snow_500m_16:NDSI_Snow_Cover')
```

Edit: I added the outer single quotes per the authors suggestion.

Comment: Wow thanks! This answer should also be in GIS Stack Exchange,